# How to get value from the last transaction, but not with today's transaction

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have data like this,

[image]

how do I get the total value from the previous transaction but not today, I try with queries like this

```
SELECT * FROM `stock` ORDER BY date_created DESC, time_created ASC
```

but the results are like this

```
| Valas  | Total | Date Created | Time Created |
| VLS001 | 13750 | 2019-05-13   | 15:15
| VLS001 | 13900 | 2019-05-11   | 14:30
| VLS001 | 13650 | 2019-05-11   | 15:39
| VLS001 | 13850 | 2019-05-10   | 15:20
```

i want to get result like this

```
| Valas  | Total | Date Created | Time Created |
| VLS001 | 13650 | 2019-05-11   | 15:39
| VLS001 | 13900 | 2019-05-11   | 14:30
| VLS001 | 13850 | 2019-05-10   | 15:20
```

I tried by making a query where date_created - 1, to get the results of the last transaction but not with today's transaction, but there was an error the previous day there was no transaction

Comment: Try something like this `SELECT * FROM stock WHERE date_created != 'today-date' ORDER BY date_created DESC, time_created ASC`

Comment: or `... WHERE date_created < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) ... `

Comment: Store dates and times as a single entity

Comment: I don't understand.  Why do you want the data on 2019-05-10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `WHERE` clause on `date_created` column specifying that the value must be different from today's date.

```
SELECT * 
FROM STOCK 
WHERE date_created != CURDATE() 
ORDER BY date_created DESC, time_created ASC;
```